# Angularjs checkbox group min and max validation restriction

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I need to validate(restrict min and max selection) check box group using angular.
     Is there any directive to achieve this validation on angular.

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Routing</title>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.controller('CHKctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.data = [{ "name": "CHK 1" },
                         { "name": "CHK 2" },
                         { "name": "CHK 3" },
                         { "name": "CHK 4" },
                         { "name": "CHK 5" },
                         { "name": "CHK 6" }];
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="CHKctrl">
    <form name="form">
        <label ng-repeat="d in data">
            <input 
                type="checkbox"
                ng-model="d.value"
                minlength="2"
                maxlength="4"/>
                {{d["name"]}} &nbsp; &nbsp;
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        {{data}}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain why would you need sth like this ?

Comment: Assume this example, list of languages 1. English 2.French 3.Japanese 4.Tamil 5.Kannada, From that validate minimum - 2 and maximum - 4.

Comment: So what you really wan to do is allow selecting only specific languages. So for that you need to implement custom validator. Reason for this is that your value in ng-model is the object not index in the list and if you check this link - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D you'll see there is no predefined validators for this field. Also in my opinion you should just hide invalid positions instead of allowing user to selct it only to display him validation error

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are;

```
<input
  ng-model="string"
  [name="string"]
  [required="string"]
  [ng-required="boolean"]
  [ng-minlength="number"]
  [ng-maxlength="number"]
  [ng-pattern="string"]
  [ng-change="string"]
  [ng-trim="boolean"]>
...
</input>
```

And you can check inputs like;

```
<tt>myForm.$error.minlength = {{!!myForm.$error.minlength}}</tt><br/>
<tt>myForm.$error.maxlength = {{!!myForm.$error.maxlength}}</tt><br/>
```

You an check at [HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input).

**For checkboxes**
Add these and improve for your requests it's a road for you;

```
<input ng-disabled="(count>max) && (!d.check)" type="checkbox" ng-checked="d.check" ng-model="d.value" minlength="2" maxlength="4" ng.click="countCheck(d)"/>
```

Js:

```
$scope.count = 0;
$scope.max = 3;
//You can swap it with ".watch"
yourController.countCheck = function(d){
    if(d.check){
        $scope.count++;
    }else{
        $scope.count--;
    }
}
```

Comment: This ng-minlength and ng-maxlength support textbox only not an checkbox group.

Comment: Please refer the link  'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959577/angularjs-checkbox-group-minimum-and-maximum-selection-validation'

Comment: For checkboxes you can't do that. You have to create a ".watch" for these checkboxes and you can count them. If count across limit you can ng-disable other checkboxes.

Comment: I tired a lot,  ctrl.$setValidity('minmax', ((min <= count) && (max >= count))); once the constraint change minmax value doesnot update.

Comment: I tired with your code, 1) I need to check both min and max. 2) Once max reached disable the checkbox then how can enable the checbox. 3) I need this validation result affect in form validation

Comment: 1. This is about form situtation. Add your ng-click to your submit button and check before submit $scope.count and if  it is okay submit your form. 2. Selected checkboxes are undisabled when you unchecked a checked box they all will seem undisabled. 3.You can create a list for selected "d"'s if checked add to list if deleted remove from list.